# monkey patch without the need to intitalise

Tags: python

I would like to money patch a function without the requirement to initialize using `pd.DataFrame.function = function`

For example, if I have a dataframe `df` and I call `df.unique()` I do not have to run `pd.DataFrame.unique = unique` prior to running as this appears to be built in. Is there a way I can do the same for my own functions without the need to initialise every time?

Comment: Do you mean that you want `pd.unique()` to call your own `unique` function without you telling it to use your own `unique` function?

Comment: I used unique as an example. My function is different. ```pd.unique(df)``` is equivalent to ```df.unique()```, the latter expression I would like to achieve with my own function without the need to monkey patch every time I do so. Can this be built into the function?

Comment: `df` is an instance of `pd.DataFrame`, so it must have been initialized at some point. Please, improve your question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, you can change the source code of pandas to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patching an existing class, e.g. `pd.DataFrame`, so that all instances have a patched method is not trivial, IMO.

What about simply subclassing `pd.DataFrame`?

```py
import pandas as pd


class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def my_func(self):
        print("yey")

df = MyDataFrame()
df.my_func()

# Outputs:
# yey
```